# Can you make a porridge from wheat flour?

Tags: substitutions, flour, oatmeal

I bake enough bread to buy flour in significant quantities; separately I buy oatmeal for quick low-effort breakfasts but don't generally use it for anything else. I would  prefer to be buying just flour for both uses. I know that farina is a wheat porridge, but it's definitely sold as a different product from wheat flour, and I am not sure whether the differences are necessary for porridge-making.

Is it possible to make a breakfast porridge from ordinary all-purpose white or whole-wheat flour?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Flour is much more finely ground than oatmeal. You can make 'porridge' with it, but it'll just be a smooth whitish goo. You might have slightly better results with whole wheat flour... It'll be more of a slightly grainy tan goo. Mmmmm.

Comment: It used to be used as wallpaper paste. Mmmmm.

Comment: To be fair, wallpaper paste is *uncooked* flour and water. Uncooked flour always tastes rank.

Comment: Also to be fair, farina is a wheat-based porridge that is also much more finely ground than oatmeal (but still less than wheat flour), and it's entirely edible. Many maize-based porridges are also much more finely ground than oatmeal. Oatmeal is the source for the coarsest porridges I know of, except maybe rice-based porridges (which go entirely unground).

Comment: Farina is made from a different part of the wheat than flour is. It's not comparable in texture or uses, regardless of how it's ground.

Answer (score 0):

Romanian ciulama is pretty much wheat porridge with some meat. It is also pretty much flavor-free.

Source: I am Romanian.

Comment: I though ciulama is served with polenta? I.e. it is not itself a porridge, it's just chicken in white sauce.